# Elasticsearch: Distance search for between two types

Tags: elasticsearch

Let’s say, I have an Elasticsearch index with two types, maybe like "train station" and "shop". These types are populated with latitude and longitude, so I can easily find all shops in a radius of 500 meters around 53.1, 9.5 and so on -- no problem.

Now I would like to find all shops which are not more than 500 meters away from a train station, but I have no idea how this is done in Elasticsearch -- does anyone has a tip for me or an advice, with which phrase I could ask Google for help?

Comment: I take you need all the routes (roads) too from the train station to the shops? Only then would be able to find the route which are not more than 500 meters right? If that is the case, then having latitude and longitude is not enough. You need the exact paths from one place to another

Comment: No, I do not want to calculate anything with routing :-)

I just want to know which shops are more or less near to a train station, so they can be reached without a car or without hours of walking. I don’t care about the exact length of the route from train to shop, I just want to know if they are somewhere next to each other.

Comment: Okay. In that case geo distance filter would solve your problem. Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to elasticsearch, but I think what you want to do is **Pipeline Aggregation**. This is the aggregation that aggregate the output of other aggregations and their associated metrics.
So get the train stations location in parent aggregation and use this info in chaining sibling. 
Hope this helps.